# What windows SDK parts are needed to run sn.exe

Tags: .net, winapi, sn.exe, delay-sign

I want to run sn.exe in order to be able to run a delayed signed project in a server. If I install the whole windows SDK everything runs smoothly, but which exact part of SDK is needed? I am asking since the whole downloading is 460Mb and probably installs stuff that I don't need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After trial & error I found out that the only part needed is .net Development -> Tools.